# Python file regex matching

Tags: python, regex, match

I am trying to extract certain words from a file using regex in python but I am unable to get it. My original file looks like

```
List/VB 
[ the/DT flights/NNS ]
from/IN
```

and I want the output to be

```
List VB 
the DT
flights NNS
from IN
```

I wrote the following code:

```
import re

with open("in.txt",'r') as infile, open("out.txt",'w') as outfile: 
    for line in infile:
        if (re.match(r'(?:[\s)?(\w\\\w)',line)):
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

with the sample data you provided:

```
>>> data = """List/VB 
... [ the/DT flights/NNS ]
... from/IN"""

>>> expr = re.compile("(([\w]+)\/([\w]+))", re.M)
>>> for el in expr.findall(data):
>>>     print el[1], el[2]
List VB
the DT
flights NNS
from IN
```

Comment: my output is printed as a array, how do i make it a string ?

Comment: do you mean you want to convert el[1] and el[2] into a single string? in that case you can do s = "%s %s" % el[1:3]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

expr = re.compile("(([\w]+)\/([\w]+))", re.M)
fp = open("file_list.txt",'r')
lines = fp.read()
fp.close()
a = expr.findall(lines)
for el in expr.findall(lines):
    print ' '.join(el[1:])
```

Outputs:

```
List VB
the DT
flights NNS
from IN
```

Comment: You should formulate your answer.